# Hyphenation with changing characters – how to do it?

Tags: languages

I am trying to create the hyphentation of Hungarian word "mellyel", which is "mely-lyel".
The basic command `\-` is not capable of adding the extra character and I did not have success with `\hyphenation` either.

I am using the Hungarian babel package and found `\babelhyphenation`, but unfortunately I was not able to make use of it (maybe I was not doing it the proper way).

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `babel` style for Hungarian provides a shorthand for that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}

blah me`llyel blah 

\hsize1pt

blah me`llyel blah 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For such hyphenations TeX has the `\discretionary` command: Use `mel\discretionary{y-}{}{}lyel`.

The three arguments after `\discretionary` describe what should be inserted before a linebreak, after a linebreak and what should be used if no break happens at all. So `\-` corresponds to `\discretionary{-}{}{}` because a hyphen should be inserted before the break, nothing after the break and the whole construct should disappear if TeX does not decide to break here at all. Your case is similar, except for the additional `y`.

Another way to write this would have been `\discretionary{mely-}{lyel}{mellyel}`, but keeping the arguments of `\discretionary` as small as possible often makes processing easier and allows addtional hyphenation points to be inserted.

If you don't want to insert this manually everytime yu use the word and use LuaLaTeX, then you can also specify this once in the beginning of your document by writing

```
\hyphenation{mely{y-}{}{}lyel}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!
Since I just registered I cannot mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks, indeed.
On the other hand, your general solution misses a `}`. I tried some re-arrangements, but they did not work.

Comment: @Marton Thanks, fixed it. If that one doesn't work for you then you probably aren't using LuaLaTeX.